# how to get all data in api without pagination in php

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a list that is paged in a limited number

And I want to store all 56 data in one variable without pagination

```
{
    "count": 56,
    "next": "https://url.com/game/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "channels": [
                {
                    "url": "https://bg-web-ostad.com/",
                    "title": "web"
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "channels": [
                {
                    "url": "https://bg-gplay-sss.com
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: it depends on the service you use, you are using php to get data from another API ? See the API documentation, you could choose how many results you want per page.
But globally, these API services will always paginate results so if you want to get all of them, you will have to send multiple requests in a loop.

Comment: Can you send a sample loop code?

Comment: You need a do-while loop, request once, store result and if there are more results, continue the do-while.